# How to i kill a java.exe with cpu usage of 0?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to know how do i kill a java.exe file with CPU usage of 0?

When i computer start up, my program will start to initiate and i realize it will have multiple java.exe file and it stop my file from running properly.

Comment: Why do you think its stopping your computer running properly? You shouldn't just kill processes. You should work out what spawning them and stop it.  Here's a guide to killing processes: https://winaero.com/blog/kill-process-windows-10/ Here's guide to checking startup processes. https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/remove-windows-10-startup-programs-3615075/

Answer (score 0):

zero CPU doesn't guarantee that process is not running. It is still consuming very small fraction of CPU.

Dos command that would be helpfull in bat file would be **taskkill /im /f xxx**.

Comment: when i start up, it will start up 3 java.exe. When i kill 2 cpu usage which is 0 , my program will then work smoothly, the one with cpu i want to remain.
Thats why i want to kill the 2 extra java.exe with 0 cpu usage

Comment: it would be better to write a Vbscrip with wmi queries

Comment: i am required to do a batch file only sir.

Comment: You need to work out what is starting them in the first place